# Uncaught TypeError cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Hello everyone I am trying to build an E-commerce project using MERN but I have some difficulties with redux-persist.

In the App.jsx the useSelector does not read the user from state

Also, in requestMethod TOKEN does not read the user, it says "cannot read property of null ("user"). Before using redux-persist, the register and login worked.

I posted the code I think there are some bugs but if you think the problems come from somewhere else I can add those files too. Thank you!

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.0",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.8.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.7.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store, persistor } from "./redux/store";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.jsx

```
import Product from './pages/Product';
import Home from './pages/Home'
import ProductList from './pages/ProductList';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import CheckOut from './pages/CheckOut';
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import Success from './components/Success';

const App = () => {
  const userId = useSelector(state => state.user.currentUser._id) 

  console.log(userId);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/products/:category' element={<ProductList />} />
        <Route path='/product/:id' element={<Product />} />
        <Route path='/checkout' element={<CheckOut />} />
        <Route path='/success' element={<Success />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={userId ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Register />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={userId ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );

};

export default App;
```

Store.js

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartReducer from "./cartRedux";
import userReducer from "./userRedux";
import {
    persistStore,
    persistReducer,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    PAUSE,
    PERSIST,
    PURGE,
    REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";


const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    version: 1,
    storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userReducer, cart: cartReducer })

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);


export const store = () => configureStore({
    reducer:
        persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            },
        })
})


export let persistor = persistStore(configureStore);
```

RequestMethods.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
const TOKEN =
    JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root')).user).currentUser
        .accessToken || "";

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    header: { token: `Viktor ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

User redux

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
        currentUser: {},
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        loginFailure: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.error = true;
        },
    },
});

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Please try state.reducer.currentUser._id

Comment: Do u mean inside of App.jsx like  "const userId = useSelector(state => state.reducer.currentUser._id) "

Comment: it did not work with const userId = useSelector(state => state.reducer.currentUser._id)

Comment: My bad. I wanted to write const userId = useSelector(state => state.reducer.user.currentUser._id)

Comment: Nope still the same output in the console, i cant even see anything on the page,  I get bundle.js:4325 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')
    at ./src/requestMethods.js (bundle.js:4325:74)
    at options.factory (bundle.js:72363:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:71805:33)
    at fn (bundle.js:72034:21)
    at ./src/pages/Product.jsx (bundle.js:3105:73)
    at options.factory (bundle.js:72363:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:71805:33)
    at fn (bundle.js:72034:21)
    at ./src/App.jsx (bundle.js:15:72)

Comment: Did you try?
store = useSelector(state => state)
console.log(store)
Did it show expected output?

Comment: I think i managed to solve the problem so far, in the requestmethods,js  I added :const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user;
const currentUser = user && JSON.parse(user).currentUser;
const TOKEN = currentUser?.accessToken;

Comment: `redux-persist` was initially made for web development. I think the `storage` is not working with `react-native`. Try this first: `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`.